# jquery ui dialog close function not work second click

Tags: jquery, function, dialog

I have a problem with ui dialog close function.

My code working first click and i see alert function.

But when i click second, then i cant see alert function. 

I need help. Example js code on link.


Thanks for your help.

http://jsfiddle.net/jHXLJ/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this line:

```
d.dialog('option', 'close', null)
```

It doesn't need to be there because you've already closed it.
That fixed the problem for me (in IE)

Answer (score 0):

In your example you can just change close to hide:

```
$("#cond").hide();
var d = $("#cond").dialog({
    width:'400',
    height:'100',
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    closeOnEscape: false,
    resizable: true,
    close: function(event, ui) {
        f();
    }
});
$('#open').click(function(){
    d.dialog('open');
});
function f(){

    d.dialog('option', 'hide', null)

    alert('hi');

}
```

Comment: Ok. I want to call function on close. How i do it ?

Comment: $( ".selector" ).bind( "dialogbeforeclose", function(event, ui) {
  ...
});


link: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#event-beforeClose

Answer (score 0):

No need to call close explicitly... I have tried this and its working....

```
function f(){

//    d.dialog('option', 'close', null)

    alert('hi');

}
```

Comment: indeed that is true, however there would be no need for the same answer twice, but nvm.. I just saw your time was only a minute after me, so you probably didn't see :)